# Laravel Test Not Validating Database Constraint

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a Laravel 5.3 app that includes a `users` table. One of the fields on that table is `api_token`, which in the database definition is set to NOT NULL. If I use Postman and hit my API endpoint for creating a user and don't include the `api_token` field, I receive the following error: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'api_token' doesn't have a default value`.

I haven't added code to the generate the token yet, so that's exactly what I'd expect. However, I have this PHPUnit test:

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_can_be_created()
{
    $this->user_data = [
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'email_address' => 'jsmith@mailinator.com',
        'phone' => '1234567890',
        'username' => 'jsmith',
        'password' => 'testing'
    ];

    $this->post('/api/users', $this->user_data, array(
                'Accept' => 'application/json'
            ))
         ->assertResponseStatus(201)
         ->seeJsonEquals(['status' => 'success'])
         ->seeInDatabase('users', $this->user_data);
}
```

The problem is that the test passes. How can this test be successful when the database should be throwing an exception when the user is saved?

I've 'died and dumped' at various points and confirmed that the data is in fact being saved to the database when the automated test runs. I've also tried using the same DB for both Postman and the automated test (instead of a separate testing DB) - same result.

Comment: Are you sure your testing against the same DB you're serving from?

Comment: For this specific example, yes

Comment: What is api_token is saved as when you run this? Does it store null or some value?

Comment: The API token saves as an empty string

Answer (score 8):

I tried to build the minimal version of your API and create a similar test on the latest Laravel 5.3.22 version. I also used MariaDB 10.1.13 for the database. And it turns out the test failed as we expected, because of the empty `api_token`.

#### 1. Users migration file

Here's my migration file for creating the `users` table:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email_address')->unique();
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('api_token');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

#### 2. The User model

Here's my `app\User.php` file looks like. Pretty minimal, I only update the `$fillable` property to match our `users` table structure:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email_address',
        'phone',
        'username',
        'password',
        'api_token',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
}
```

#### 3. The API routes file

I create a new API route on `routes/api.php` file to create a new user. Super simple without any validation involved:

```
Route::post('users', function (Request $request) {
    $data = $request->only([
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email_address',
        'phone',
        'username',
        'password',
        'api_token',
    ]);

    if (is_string($data['password'])) {
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
    }

    $user = App\User::create($data);

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
    ], 201);
});
```

#### 4. Create user API test

And finally here's my test file for testing our create user API.

```
class ApiTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function a_user_can_be_created()
    {
        $user = [
            'first_name' => 'Jane',
            'last_name' => 'Smith',
            'email_address' => 'jsmith@mailinator.com',
            'phone' => '1234567890',
            'username' => 'jsmith',
        ];

        $this->json('POST', 'api/users', $user)
            ->assertResponseStatus(201)
            ->seeJsonEquals(['status' => 'success'])
            ->seeInDatabase('users', array_except($user, ['password']));
    }
}
```

The only difference is I used `array_except()` to exclude the `password` column from database testing since we hashed the value before storing it in the database. But of course this does not relate to your issue.

When I run the test without the `api_token` being set, the test failed as expected. The API return a status code of 500, while we expected it to be 201.

[image: The create user API failed!]

Also as a reference, when I set the `api_token` column as NOT nullable, then force to create a new user with an empty `api_token`, the exception message I received is like this:

> **QueryException in Connection.php line 769:**
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'api_token' cannot be null (SQL: insert into users...

Hope this help you debug your issue!

Comment: Thanks for the rundown. I should've specified that I'm using MySQL - I think that might account for the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using mysql. In mysql there is a problem with `NOT NULL`. It goes like this. Although the field is `NOT NULL` you can leave it empty in mysql and the query passes. `NOT NULL` in mysql means that you can't have `NULL` value in that field not that you can't leave it empty. I assume you create the user as this

```
User::create($request->all())
```

If you try to print the generated sql query

```
dd((new User($request->all())->toSql())
```

You will see that the generated query contains `''` value for `api_token` field

I switched to posgres mainly because this problem.

If you want to solve this problem you have couple of options. One is to leave the `api_token` field nullable. The second one is to fill the model manually

Comment: Good catch - this might be related to the underlying issue (you're right that it works when I pass "api_token":"" in my json in Postman). What's odd, however, is that when I dump the SQL that is run when I run the automated test, I get this: "insert into `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email_address`, `phone`, `username`, `password`, `user_type_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)". So it doesn't look like PHPUnit is adding "api_token" as an empty string. Shouldn't that cause a MySQL error?

Comment: When `api_token` field is not added it works. If you `api_token` field is added as NULL then it doesn't work

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is that for me, that's not true. When I pass the same data from my test (which does not include the api_token field), I get that error I pasted into my question

Answer (score 1):

You should define a default value to your `api_token` column in `users` table or it should be set to `nullable`, your migration for users table would be like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('api_token')->nullable();
    // Or you can set it to default value - 0
    // $table->string('api_token')->default('0');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I'll end up setting it to nullable, but I still want to understand why the tests aren't behaving as I'd expect

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the Unit Test. Why don't you try with a Laravel test using Eloquent? Something like this:

```
public function a_user_can_be_created()
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->first_name = 'Jane';
    $user->last_name = 'Smith';
    $user->email_address = 'jsmith@mailinator.com';
    $user->phone = '1234567890';
    $user->username = 'jsmith';
    $user->password = 'testing';

    $user->save();

    return $user;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/testing

Comment: I'll check this when I have a chance and see if I see similar behavior using your example. In my example though, I'm specifically trying to test an API, so I was following this convention: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing#testing-json-apis

Comment: Your approach makes sense to me keeping in mind you are testing an API.. but if it's making a version of the user model in json, then that's your answer. The api_token is in there, buy empty